# Should I use 'on' or 'for' in these sentences?

Tags: american-english, speech

If I called the ER about a patient of whom a doctor is taking care, should I say, 'may I speak to the doctor **on** the patient name John? I have a result **on** this patient?" or should I use for, "may i speak to the doctor **for** the patient name John? I have a result **for** this patient?" Thank you.

Answer (score -1):

You are looking for a possessive like, „the doctor‘s patient“, but you cannot say „the doctor on the patient.“ That’s not grammatically possible. Something like „The doctor for the patient“ might be possible in some carefully drawn narrow sentences, like „For this patient, we have assigned Dr. XYZ,“ but otherwise this preposition will not work either. What you need to use is an entirely different sentence structure, like „May I speak with the doctor taking care of (or caring for) this patient.“

Comment: Please edit all your posts that have the wrong sort of quotation marks so that they are correct in written English.